# Exchange 2010, Cannot ADD new user to Delivery Option, Set-Mailbox Failed, Error: Couldn't find object, Send on Behalf, isn't the expected type

Tags: configuration, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

***Aim:***

- Try to add new user to "Delivery Options -> Send on Behalf -> Grant this permission to:".
- This is found in:

> Mailbox -> Properties -> Mail Flow Settings -> Delivery Options

***Issue:***

- Failed to add new user to "Delivery Options"
- Got error message

> Error: Couldn't find object "DOMAINxxxx/OUxxxx/USERxxxx". Please make
>   sure that it was spelled correctly or specify a different object.
>   Reason: The recipient DOMAINxxxx/OUxxxx/USERxxxx isn't the expected
>   type.

- But **USERxxxx** is **NOT** in the list of "Grant this permission
  to"
- Also **USERxxxx** is has already been **DISABLED** in Active Directory

***Attempted Fix:***

- Confirmed **PublicDelegates** is set to **"not set"**

> ADSI edit -> USERxxxx -> Properties -> PublicDelegates

- Re-enabled **USERxxxx** account in **Active Directory** and then tried to ADD new user, still **FAILED**

***Current Fix Result:***

- Exchange **FAILED** to add new user to "Delivery Options" even the "PublicDelegates" has no value in "ADSI edit"

***Reference Picture of the issue:***
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.
Make sure to remove **"PublicDelegates"** from **USERxxxx**'s account and also the mailbox you would like to add new account in.

Previously I removed **"PublicDelegates"** from **USERxxxx**'s account only, therefore the issue was persistent.

Also once you removed the first **USERxxxx** from the error message, you might get another **USERxxxx2** with same issue. In this case repeat the steps above until all error goes away, then you will be able to add new user in the mailbox.